# How can I input line-sparator in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

In some elisp file, they use line-sparator(I have no idea what is the name of it) to sparate some functions.

Some functions maybe be called only by some functions which will be made for API for user. So the two part of functions are different.

In some elisp file, there a one charator which display like a line in Emacs(I call it line-sparator).

For example, in help.el file, after the line `(defvar help-button-cache nil)` , there is a line-sparator in line 114.

So, My question is How to input it in Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `C-q C-l` I believe. This inserts the `^L` escape, which is commonly known as a [`FORM_FEED`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break). Traditionally, this command was used to tell printers to eject the page and start a new one; of course, this has changed over time. Normally, this is used as a directive to clear the screen in terminals.

I'm not sure what you're seeing, because the character displays as `^L` to me.

EDIT: sniped.

Comment: install the page-break-lines-modes package and run `turn-on-page-break-lines-mode` will display the line.

Answer (score 4):

This character is called "form feed", shown in Emacs as `^L`, represented in files as byte 12 (decimal) / 0C (hex).  Its function is to separate pages; when sent to a printer, it will usually make the printer output the current page and restart output at the top of a new page.

You can input it with `C-q C-l`.  `C-q` is bound to `quoted-insert`, which can insert almost anything into the buffer literally.

Comment: What is the common etiquette when two answers are posted at the same time, with almost exactly the same content?